# Работа с IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript

Очень мало хороших различных пример работы с IntersectionObserver. Для меня он все еще не понятен, да и думаю многим, кто только впервые начинает с ним работать, но у людей имевшие хороший с ним опыт я думаю есть уже некоторые "шаблоны". Так вот.. Можете ли вы предоставить какие-то базовые и уровнем выше примеры работы?

(Прошу, не нужно кидать минусы, если данный вопрос не относится к тематике сайта. Лично я считаю, что он относится т.к. в данном вопросе есть тема, которую смогут найти другие и примеры работы.)

---

- Допустим у нас есть какой-то сайдбар, в котором есть скролл. В нем есть элементы `<li>`, данные элементы могут подгружаться динамически, то есть при прокрутке вниз, в DOM добавятся еще `<li>`, а вверху лишние удаляются. Этот сайд бар не на всю высоту экрана. Нужно определить когда элемент `<li>` появляется в зоне видимости.
- Есть обычный блок, который нужно отследить, когда он появляется в зоне видимости, когда пропадает.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы задали конкретный вопрос на конкретном примере. Иначе вы рискуете получить абстрактный ответ, который вы и так можете прочитать на образовательных ресурсах.

Comment: Ваш вопрос из разряда - очень мало примеров работы с молотком, очень непонятно, как с ним работать. IntersectionObserver - инструмент, его применение зависит от задачи.

Comment: Имхо: шаблоны только уводят от понимания, т.е. имеют отрицательный эффект. Полезным будет рассуждение/разбор применения инструмента в **конкретной воспроизводимой задаче из области программирования** - тогда как набор "шаблонов" для копипаста, бесполезен: он лишь потенциально создает массу производных некачественных вопросов от других участников, типа "нашол код в интернети, хачу чтобы он делол мне другое, памагити" (т.е. куски копипаст-кода мало того что не учат, они еще и провоцируют появление на SO запросов выполнения работ, вместо вопросов, тем самым являясь поощрением плохой практики).

Comment: @yar85, ну я не совсем согласен. Кому действительно нужно, те будут разбирать код и вникать в него. Кому это не нужно, будут с любым кодом так спрашивать.

Comment: Кому действительно нужно, разберутся и без шаблонов кода :) Им будет достаточно справочника (МДН/спеки) - вот это уже не мнение или предположение, а твердая уверенность основанная на практическом опыте, т.е. фактах (но в нее предлагаю не верить, предлагаю это _проверить_).

Comment: Как оказалось, в справке довольно мало применений. Первым же делом я полез туда естественно.